# SIte not rendering on Github pages

Tags: javascript, github, npm, rendering

I worked on some project and when I uploaded on Github, site's not rendering. I think only JS file is not working. Another problem is that if I open index.html locally, it's not working either. If I run with "npm run dev" then it works perfectly. I'm using Vite and npm on projects to work more fast while I'm coding.

I tried to upload again on github. checking file path.
https://github.com/einstyr/The-Planets.git this is repository link

Comment: What's wrong with https://einstyr.github.io/The-Planets/ ?

Comment: Now I fixed it somehow. Don`t know how. But I have another problem. In desktop version, when I open responsive dev tool, looks perfect but when I open site from mobile, things is screwed. It opens zoomed, navigation links not working and elements are laping each=other

Comment: And now it stopped rendering again without me doing anything...

Comment: Re-deploying the pages on github.io takes a while after every change you make to the github.com repository.

Comment: please create [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.